# Can I upgrade galaxy s5 firmware of different region

Tags: samsung-mobile, galaxy

Can I upgrade my galaxy s5 model SM-G900I to the firmware of another country/region but of same model no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! You can. But, for doing it you need to change your phone's `CSC` code.
`Samsung was using an special CSC file included in Android firmware which are specifically built and designates to each country or mobile network providers.`

Changing the CSC code to the corresponding country's CSC of which you want to flash the firmware will work for you!

Comment: @babu : Kindly give an upvote :)